# Select either PayPal or Purchase Order from a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, paypal

I have a registration form where there are 2 options (radio buttons) for Payment.

1. PayPal
2. Purchase Order

Since the PayPal button is within it's own form, I am unable to nest it in my original form.

Currently the way I had it set up was with Javascript to hide the po number field when PayPal was selected and hide the nested PayPal form when the PO button is selected.

However since I can't have multiple "Submit" buttons, I am trying to find a way to only show one or the other based upon the selection of the radio button.

Comment: You've any attempt in php? Could you make a form to re-post automatically ?

Comment: Currently the Submit button is sending the form data via email using PHP, but I don't know how to make a form re-post automatically.

Comment: It can be an answer to you if I told you how do it?

Comment: It's easy to set up. And yes you can have multiple submit buttons. Just give them different names

Comment: Can you post up the form and the javascript code to see what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do it something like this to RE-POST a form. Maybe it can be useful to your solution for redirect with a post.

```
echo "<html>";
echo "<body onload='document.forms[""yourSecondForm""].submit()'>";
echo "<form name='yourSecondForm' action='" . $_YOUR_URL_VAR_THAT_COMING_FROM_OTHER_POST . "' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='" . $SOME_VAR_NAME . "' value='" . $SOME_VAR_VALUE . "'>";
echo "</form>");
echo "</body>");
echo "</html>");
```